# How to access a specific index of an array in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get only the `AID` from the solution now i am getting. I tried `rows[0]` but was not successful.

Code:

```
console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
```

Output:

```
The solution is:
[ { AID: 6520,
    DID: 113071,
    TITLE: 'First Knight',
    DATE: '7/7/1995',
    SCORE: 89 } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rows[0]["AID"]` to access the `AID` property.

Comment: `rows[0].AID` is a usually preferred notation

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand your overall data structure here:

```
var rows = [ 
 { 
    AID: 6520,
    DID: 113071,
    TITLE: 'First Knight',
    DATE: '7/7/1995',
    SCORE: 89 
  } 
];
```

The variable `rows` is an array of objects.  Thus `rows[n]` gets you a specified object in that array  and therefore `rows[0]` is the first object in the array which would be:

```
 { 
    AID: 6520,
    DID: 113071,
    TITLE: 'First Knight',
    DATE: '7/7/1995',
    SCORE: 89 
  }
```

So, now you want to access the `AID` property in that object so you can just do:

```
rows[0].AID
```

---

And, here's a working snippet demo:

```js
var rows = [ 
 { 
    AID: 6520,
    DID: 113071,
    TITLE: 'First Knight',
    DATE: '7/7/1995',
    SCORE: 89 
  } 
];

document.write(rows[0].AID);
```